# Динамически увеличивающееся окно в зависимости от содержимого

Tags: javascript, html

Добрый день!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, я сделал всплывающее окошко по технологии двух div-ов (1 большой и затемненный, другой - маленький и светлый). При открытии всплывающего окошка div заполняется HTML-код таблицы, а **таблицы бывают маленькие и большие** - поэтому нужно, чтобы **низ всплыв. окошка двигался вверх/вниз, в зависимости от размеров таблицы**.

Может свойство какое CSS надо прописать? Или еще какой метод есть?

Comment: position:relative; - динамическая высота заработала, но получается что всплывающее окошко в центре окна, и хочется чтобы оно было ближе к верхней границе экрана. Можете подсказать как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Доброго времени суток.

Такое страшное дело можно сварганить в **jQuery**.

Итак, погнали:

**CSS:**

```
/* Темный фон */
.background{
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

/* Окошко */
.window{
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  margin: 100px auto 100px auto;
  width: 300px;
  color: #000000;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class='background'>
  <div class='window'>
    <table id='table'>
      <tr>
        <td>Большая и маленькая таблица.</td>
      </tr>
    <table>
</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.window').css({height:$('#table').height()+"px"}); 
});
```

Вот таким образом это дело можно организовать.

Answer (score 0):

Можно не задавать высоту в css - тогда окошко само отмасштабируется как ему удобно. А с помощью jquery можно вычислить его высоту и отцентровать как удобно.

Comment: Вариант опробовал - не вышло. Мне хром нарисовал панель до нижней границы экрана.  Есть еще какой-то способ?

Comment: Если таблица слишком высокая, можно с помощью jquery уменьшить высоту панели и прописать прокрутку внутри нее.

Comment: так нельзя сделать, в смысле запретили. я вот так сделал: position:relative;  и динамически высота работает - как и надо, но получается что окошко в центре окна, и хочется чтобы оно было ближе к верхней границе экрана. Можете подсказать как это можно сделать?

Comment: `margin-top: -100px;` или `top: 100px;` - исходя из задачи.

Answer (score 0):

```
div{
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: пробовал - писал  height: auto; все равно - окошко до нижней границы доходит!(